# Value undefined onChange multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am using multiselect drop down, I want to get value `onChange` event. I have two functions main function and function b, function b I am using for `onChange` event.

I have created object of function b to get it's value in main function.

I want to get it's value in main function.

Now problem is function b is getting value on change but not showing it if I create object.

If I assign string to `this.selected_cats = 'some string';` it shows perfectly in main function. But if I assign selected category to `this.selected_cats = elem;` it says undefined in console. If I say  `onChange="alert(this.value)";` this shows me value fine.

```
function b (elem){
 this.selected_cats = elem;
};

var obj_b = new b();

function main(){
   console.log(obj_b.selected_cats);
}

<select name='category[]' id="select_cats" onchange="b(this.value);" multiple="multiple">
```

This way it shows me value fine also 🠟🠟🠟
I mean without using object

```
  function b (elem){
  var show_value = elem;
  console.log(show_value);
  };
```

Comment: Is it ok with give you a different approach to get all selected values?

i.e do u want us to debug code or solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be calling a function on your instance of `b` in order to changes its values.  EG:

```
function b (elem){
 this.selected_cats = elem;
};

var obj_b = new b();
obj_b.onChange = function (elem){
 this.selected_cats = elem;
};

function main(){
   console.log(obj_b.selected_cats);
}

<select name='category[]' id="select_cats" onchange="obj_b.onChange(this.value);" multiple="multiple">
```